# Nested g vs svg

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm building out some responsive SVG-based components (based around Backbone views). The convention I'm using is that when a component is created, it is provided with a DOM element to render itself into. When rendering, the component checks the size of the DOM element and fills the entire available space.

I was using `g` elements, but they don't have their own width and height; they just match their contents. So I made a hack where I would append a `rect` that was the size I needed. This works pretty well, but it is hacky.

Today I discovered that `svg` elements can be nested just like `g`, but they're also able to have their own width and height. I just tested it out and it seems to work great. Are there any downsides I'm missing creating a bunch of nested `svg` elements like this?

Comment: One of the best resources around is Sara Soueidan's three-part series [*Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations*](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems) covering all the gory details of SVG's coordinates in a very informative way. *Part 3* contains a section about [*Nesting* `<svg>>` *Elements*](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/nesting-svgs/#nesting-svgs) which should provide all the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There shouldn't be any downsides to using nested `<svg>` elements. But your description of what you are doing is rather vague, so I can't guarantee that you won't strike any in your particular use case.